# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Message should not be empty

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I try to sign a list of numbers from 0 to 9 using this function:
`eccrypto.sign(privateKey, msg);` from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eccrypto) .

The problem is when I use for loop, forEach or any loop format, the function does not work with 'await', this is my function:

newfun=(async ()=>{

```
  var eccrypto = require("eccrypto");
    
  var privateKey= Buffer.from([238, 239, 199, 101, 188, 134, 13, 13, 195, 172, 125, 168, 225, 189, 72, 148, 225, 200, 127, 218, 204, 11, 150, 146, 180, 243, 195, 109, 200, 119, 50, 20],'hex');


  for (var msg=0; msg<=10;i++) {      
    var encrypt=await eccrypto.sign(privateKey, msg);
    
 }});
```

and this what I got:

[image]
I search a lot, there were some different suggestions such as using: Promise, but neither it works for me.
can I get help with this! thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think `sign` accepts a _number_ as message argument, also the readme you linked says `// Always hash you message to sign!` `var msg = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(str).digest();` and you didn't do that either. It has nothing to do with promises or loops or async, I'd say.

Comment: Sounds very much like `.sign()` expects a Buffer from a [Hash.digest()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_digest_encoding), not a number.

Comment: yes, none of the ***documentation*** shows `.sign` being used on a `Number`

Comment: Oh! silly question ): Actually, I need it without hashing, so you are right; the problem was a number ): it works when I convert the number to a string @CherryDT